# Do I need to register as self employed in Ontario, Canada?

Tags: canada, self-employment, ontario

I am moving from UK, where I am registered as self employed under my own name, to Ontario, Canada.  In Canada I will be both employed in a full time job and self employed, making a small amount of side income.

I have read that I only need to register my self employed business if I want to trade under any other business name than my own name.  And then, any income I make through self employment is simply declared on my end of year tax return.  Is this true?

Comment: What kind of business? How much anticipated business revenue per year?

Answer (score 4):

If your business name is your name, you are automatically considered a sole-proprietorship and any income you generate and expenses you incur can be calculated on your personal tax return. You can use QuickTax Home & Business tax software to lead you through the steps; you don't even need an accountant.

One drawback of a sole-proprietorship in your name is liability. You are personally responsible for the business because you *are* the business. If you get sued, you can lose everything. To limit that liability you can look into opening a corporation. If the corporation gets sued you are insulated from that; the corporation goes bankrupt, not you. A lawyer and an accountant will be required to give you solid advice on this direction.